# How do I draw pixels with GIMP Python's gimp-drawable-set-pixel?

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu

Currently I have this code:

```
def my_script_function(image, drawable, text_value, int_value) :
   pixel = [0,0, 255, 255]
   for i in range(1,1600):
      for j in range(1,1600):
         pdb.gimp_drawable_set_pixel(drawable, i, j, 4, pixel)
   #gimp.set_background(02, 100, 255)
   pdb.gimp_image_flip( image, ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL )
   return
```

`pdb.gimp_image_flip( image, ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL )` works fine, however, `pdb.gimp_drawable_set_pixel(drawable, i, j, 4, pixel)` returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\lib\gimp\2.0\python\gimpfu.py", line 699, in response
    dialog.res = run_script(params)
  File "C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\lib\gimp\2.0\python\gimpfu.py", line 361, in run_script
    return apply(function, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins\Example1.py", line 15, in my_script_function
    pdb.gimp_drawable_set_pixel(drawable, i, j, 4, pixel)
RuntimeError: execution error
```

Which, just tells me for some reason it's not running `pdb.gimp_drawable_set_pixel(drawable, i, j, 4, pixel)`

If you want to try it out, here's the entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *

# create an output function that redirects to gimp's Error Console
def gprint( text ):
   pdb.gimp_message(text)
   return 

# our script
def my_script_function(image, drawable, text_value, int_value) :
   pixel = [0,0, 255, 255]
   for i in range(1,1600):
      for j in range(1,1600):
         pdb.gimp_drawable_set_pixel(drawable, i, j, 4, pixel)
   #gimp.set_background(02, 100, 255)
   pdb.gimp_image_flip( image, ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL )
   return

# This is the plugin registration function
register(
    "my_first_script2",    
    "Hamburger",   
    "This script draws some stuff2",
    "asdf", 
    "asdf Company", 
    "asdf 2015",
    "<Image>/MyScripts/My First Python-Fu", 
    "*", 
    [
      (PF_STRING, 'some_text', 'Some text input for our plugin', 'Write something'),
      (PF_INT, 'some_integer', 'Some number input for our plugin', 2010)
    ], 
    [],
    my_script_function,
    )

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
guint8 pixel[] = { 0xff, 0, 0, 0xff };
```

Is C not python and is invalid python syntax try:

```
pixel = [0xff, 0, 0, 0xff]
```

Comment: I knew it looked different. Anyway, I changed that and I get the original error from when I wrote `array(255,0,0)` for the pixel value, the error was `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'module' and 'gimp.Layer'`